# Processing Multi-form data in Netty

Tags: java, forms, httprequest, netty, form-processing

With a client like this

```
StringBody body = new StringBody("form_username", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
multipart.addPart("username", body);
ByteArrayBody bBody = new ByteArrayBody(bs, "form_command.dat");
multipart.addPart("data", bBody);
httppost.setEntity(multipart);
```

How are the values supposed to be retrieved in the netty server. I already have a HttpRequestDecoder added to the pipeline. And the messageReceived  handled thus

```
HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();
    this.mRequest = request;


    if (is100ContinueExpected(request)) {
        send100Continue(e);
    }

    ChannelBuffer content = request.getContent();
    if (content.readable()) {

        System.out.println("Content()\n" + content.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8) + "\r\n");


    }
```

Print outputs .

```
Content()
--Xdq2t6unVsUp191MKhpR6BXz5P7Eoo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

form_username
--Xdq2t6unVsUp191MKhpR6BXz5P7Eoo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="form_command.dat"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary



--Xdq2t6unVsUp191MKhpR6BXz5P7Eoo--


End of contents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the new [HttpPostRequestDecoder](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpPostRequestDecoder.java).  This is only available in the upcoming Netty 3.5 (3 branch) and Netty 4 (master branch).

Here an example [usage](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/upload/HttpUploadServerHandler.java).

If you need to use it now, you can just copy the files mentioned in this [pull request](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/286) into your project namespace and use it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried to backport the updates, but got stuck in resolving SeekAheadOptimize which I believe should be in HttpPostBodyUtil. Is there a downloadable jar file of this backports. or git commands to get the "back-ported" files. Thanks.

Comment: Here's one that I've done. https://github.com/mashupbots/socko/tree/master/socko-webserver/src/main/java/org/mashupbots/socko/postdecoder.

Comment: Planning to get rid of it once 3.5 has been released.

Comment: all links have been expired